# use json object in javascript to show in confirm window

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp, spring-mvc

Creating json object in controller,

```
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
          for (BaseLoad b : bagsToLink) {
              JSONObject loadJSON = new JSONObject();
              loadJSON.put("Name", b.getName());
              loadJSON.put("Load", b.getLoad());
              jArray.put(loadJSON);
           }
        jObject.put("loadList", jArray);
        uldSelector.setJsonObject(jObject.toString());
   } catch (JSONException jse) {
        jse.printStackTrace();
    }
```

sending jsonObject as string from controller, jsonObject is something like this:

```
    {"loadList":[{"Name":"AAAA","Load":"N GND"},
                  {"Name":"BBBB","Load":"N GND"},
                  {"Name":"CCCC","Load":"N GND"},
                  {"Name":"DDDD","Load":"N GND"}]
     } );
```

I need to use the above text in a java script confirm window like,

```
Name:AAAA Load:N GND
Name:BBBB Load:N GND
Name:CCCC Load:N GND
Name:DDDD Load:N GND
```

what I am doing is `var obj = $.parseJSON( ${jsonObject} );` but `obj` turn out to be null!

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you show some more code?

Comment: @DirkLachowski added how I am creating the json string in controller

Comment: If the JSON-String you are trying to parse is really the one you are showing in your question then it's malformed (the ');' at the end). Could you check that?

Comment: @DirkLachowski where is it? i didn't see anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can't add an image to a comment, here it is, as an answer.

[image: Malformed part]